# What is the biggest bearing that I can find in car?

Tags: bearing

I want to buy [inner bearing puller set](https://www.kukko.com/en/produkt/mp_25/25-a/) for car maintenance( sedan, off-road, SUV).

Which set diameter should be sufficient?

- 12 - 46 mm
- 12 - 70 mm
- 12 - 110 mm

I don't wont to buy too small of a tool and be surprised one day.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Something you should think about when going for a puller set is a set which does two jaw and will convert to three jaw. This will not only allow for you to do internal pulling like on a bearing (though I usually use a brass drift to get most bearing races out). If you get a decent set with two sizes, it will cover about 90+% of anything you'll need. This is JMHO, though I'm not sure anyone else will have anything better for you.

Comment: 12-70 should cover you on most all cars and light trucks.

Comment: I already have two jaw puller for external bearings. Thats why I wanted something for internal bearing. In the end I went with 12-46. Why? I figured out that the biggest bearings are usually in wheel hub and differentials. But they don't require internal puller set and some of them are even smaller than 45mm. So I thing 12-46 will cover my cases and I wont get suprpsed. Thanks guys for help.